# Deleting (updating) coreData objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am developing an iOS application and i am using `CoreData` to persiste my data. The application is like iBooks, we can download a book, read a book, takes notes in the book,... and for this i have many entities in `CoreData` (`NoteEntity`,....). 
Now i have a functionality witch is removing a book downloaded by the user ( the user can download many books and there are a functionality to delete a book ( to have spaces for example)). My question is, is there a simple way to remove all the objects in CoreData ( all the objects corresponding to the book deleted by the user) Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Say something about your model. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a "Cascade" delete relationship between the book and all objects associated with it.

From [Core Data programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html):

> **Relationship Delete Rules:** A relationship's delete rule specifies what
>   should happen if an attempt is made to delete the source object. Note
>   the phrasing in the previous sentence—"if an attempt is made…". If a
>   relationship's delete rule is set to Deny, it is possible that the
>   source object will not be deleted. Consider again a department's
>   employees relationship, and the effect that the different delete rules
>   have.
>
> ...
>
> **Cascade:** 
>   Delete the
>   objects at the destination of the relationship. For example, if you
>   delete a department, fire all the employees in that department at the
>   same time.