# Core Data Nullify rule doesn't work?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a relationship `Order<-->>Row` with both relationship delete rules set to `Nullify`. But when I delete a row as below, it is not removed from the Order's row-list?

```
// Prints "1" as there is one row in the order
NSLog(@"Number of children before: %d", order.rows.count);

for (Row *row in order.rows)
    [moc deleteObject:row];

// Prints "1", should be "0"
NSLog(@"Number of children after: %d", order.rows.count);
```

This can force the behavior, but it shouldn't be needed. What might be wrong?

```
for (Row *row in order.rows)
{
    [moc deleteObject:row];
    [order removeRowsObject:row];
}
```

Comment: Is your relationship ordered ? Do you know that the implementation of Apple for ordered relationships is bugged ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what nullify does. Use cascade instead. I answered a similar question to this 2 days ago, look at it if you need more detail: [Deleting (updating) coreData objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11631001/1487063)

Comment: Won't Cascade delete the Order if it is set on the Row->Order relationship? If not, what is it that Nullify do in this case?

Comment: Nullify sets the pointer to null when the object is deleted. If you have an array of pointers it doesn't remove it, it just sets it to null.