# Are Core Data relationships used in the real world?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm very familiar with Core Data but I haven't found any practical use for Core Data relationships. I know conceptually what they should do but they don't seem to enforce anything. Standard concepts such as primary/foreign key, cascading deletes, deleting a value you shouldn't be able to because of relationship constraints don't seem to be enforced.

Am I reading all of that wrong? Do Core Data relationships actually have enforceable constraints?

Comment: This might help: "How validation works in Core Data" in the [Object Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ObjectValidation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH20-SW1) section of the Core Data Programming Guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can control the relationship by setting different delete rules.

Consult with this guide for more information on available configuration points: [Creating Managed Object Relationships](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html)

It's worth noting that the rules are enforced only during `save()`.

Comment: Thanks. So the whole world of Core Data relationships only works during a save()? I guess I wasn't far off in my thinking on this topic.

Comment: Also check this answer, it has some practical examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837832/when-does-core-data-nullify-rule-update-relations

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be thinking of Core Data in SQL-style terms, which is a mistake. Its API is not SQL-ish even though it's often used as something like a database.

Most directly-- foreign keys are not a "standard concept" unless you assume that Core Data should follow SQL rules. Relationships in Core Data are generally used **in place of** foreign keys. You use the relationship to indicate that one object is related to some other object. It's similar to how SQL might use a foreign key to relate an entry in one table to an entry in another table, but it's not the same thing.

Are they used in the "real world"? Of course-- Core Data would be a lot less useful if it didn't have relationships. They're the Core Data equivalent of an object having a property that is also an object of some kind.